# What do I need to do to trigger my Yongnuo 560IVs reliably from a distance and behind objects?

Tags: troubleshooting, yongnuo, wireless-flash

I am shooting with Canon 7D Mark II and I am currently trying to get into the flash photography. I am still working on a budget so I started with  two Yongnuo YN-560IVs and a YN-560-TX transmitter.

I am shooting lots of sports and the first time trying these flashes I realized that my flashes won't fire when I place them farther away. I need the flashes to fire from 15m-20m.  And I need triggers that can fire my flash even it's placed behind some subject.

I am thinking about buying wireless triggers, but I am not sure which ones to choose. I was looking at the Yongnuo YN-622C TTL, but read elsewhere that it's not compatible with my 7D Mark II. I am not sure what to look for to get triggers that will work with what I have that will do what I need.

Also I'm not sure if I can use my YN-560-TX controller to communicate with transceivers or do I need to buy a wireless flash controller instead (mine says manual)?

Comment: Welcome to Photo.SE! We tend to avoid product recommendation questions here as they become outdated quickly and are often too specific to help other readers. Sites like Amazon and B&H Photo are usually good sources of information to help with your purchasing decision.

Comment: The YN-622C system is fully compatible with the 7D Mark II. Just remember that it is a *radio* control system. Prior to the RT series of flashes Canon's own wireless E-TTL control system was *optical* and the cameras with built-in flash retain the ability to control those older flashes optically. But that is true of all of the Canon cameras/flashes. To use any Canon optically controlled flash with a *radio* controller the flash needs a radio receiver - whether an external one or an internal one such as your YN-560IVs have built into them. But not all radio systems speak the same language.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure what to look for to get triggers that will work with what I have that will do what I need.

The gear you have should already do everything you need. The YN-560-TX specs out to a 100m range; and anecdotally there are folks getting 200m range out of it. The YN-560 triggering system is also radio-based, so it should not have any line-of-sight issues.

> Also I'm not sure if I can use my YN-560-TX controller to communicate with transceivers or do I need to buy a wireless flash controller instead (mine says manual)?

And even though it's manual-only you can still control the power level and zoom settings on your remote lights from the TX. And the YN-560 IVs have built-in transceivers, so you don't need them as long as you're using the YN-560-TX or an RF-603/603II/605 as your transmitter.  If you switch to the 622 system, however, you will need to add YN-622s to each flash.

But I don't think you need new triggers. You haven't mentioned requiring HSS or TTL (which would be the main reason to move to the 622s, although the Godox X1 might be a better bet for future expansion).  What's more likely is that something's incorrectly configured in your setup.

- Did you check your flashes were firing correctly without the triggers (good batteries, in working order; use the test button).
- Are the batteries in the TX unit good?
- Is everything on the same channel?
- Are your YN-560IVs in radio slave mode? (not radio master, not optical slave)
- Did everything work at closer distances?
- Is the transmitter seated properly on the hotshoe of the camera?
- Have you checked all pins/hotshoe contacts are clean on the flashes, camera, and triggers?
- Are you getting the blue light indicating the trigger is paired?
- Is there radio interference in the area where you want to shoot? Did you try different channels?